# Creating a Parallel Array for Rainfall Program

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written most of my rainfall program and all of the functions work how I need them to. I get the total, average, and minimum and maximum rainfall for the user inputs using an array.

I have a const string array for the month names but I need the to display on lines 116 and 119 where I have the "month" comment, or something similar.

Also, is there a way I could have the month names display with the user input instead of 1: 2: etc..? If not, that isn't the most pressing thing to solve.

Below is my current code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12;

double inputValidate(double user_number);
void getValues(double []);
double Total(double []);
double average(double);
double GetMinRainfall(double []);
double GetMaxRainfall(double []);
void display(double, double, double, double);

int main()
{
    double rainfall[ARRAY_SIZE];

    cout << "Enter Average Rainfall for Each Month:" << endl;

    getValues(rainfall);
 
    double total_rainfall = Total(rainfall);
    double average_rainfall = average(total_rainfall);
    double minimum_rainfall = GetMinRainfall(rainfall);
    double maximum_rainfall = GetMaxRainfall(rainfall);

    display(total_rainfall, average_rainfall, minimum_rainfall, maximum_rainfall);

    return 0;
}

double inputValidate(double user_number)
{
    while (!(cin >> user_number) || user_number < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error: please enter a positive number." << "Try again: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    return user_number;
}

void getValues(double array[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << (i + 1) << ": ";
        array[i] = inputValidate(array[i]);
    }
}

double Total(double array[])
{
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        total += array[i];

    return total;
}

double average(double total)
{
    return total / ARRAY_SIZE;
}

double GetMinRainfall(double array[]) 
{
    double min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (min > array[i])
            min = array[i]; 
    }
     
    return min;
}

double GetMaxRainfall(double array[])
{
    double max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (max < array[i])
            max = array[i]; 
    }
    
    return  max;
}

void display(double total, double average, double minimum_rainfall, double maximum_rainfall)
{
    const string MONTHS[12] = {
        "January", "February", "March", 
        "April" , "May" , "June",
        "July" , "August" , "September",
        "October", "November", "December"
    }; 

    cout << "Total Rainfall for the year is " << total << " inches.";
    cout << "\nAverage Rainfall for the year is " << average << " inches.";
    cout << "\nThe least rain fell in "<< /* month */ "with " << minimum_rainfall << " inches."; 
     
    cout << "\nThe most rain fell in "<< /* month */ "with "<< maximum_rainfall << " inches.";
}
```

Comment: what's your question? How to index the `MONTHS` array? You've already shown you know how to index an array elsewhere. Or are you asking how to find the index of the min/max rainfall? You're already doing that too, just need to save the index `i` where each extreme occurs. You can pass that argument by reference and continue to return the rainfall value like you already are.

Comment: Generally the answer to "how to implement parallel lists/arrays?" is _don't_. Instead have _one_ array of objects which store multiple pieces of related data.

Comment: Yano - Thank you I think I understand this concept and I will try that first.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to collect figures for rainfall amount for each month and then output which month had the most and least rainfall. The total and average bits are not the issue. It's how to correlate that min and max back to month names.

*If* we go down the parallel array rabbit hole, then indexes are key. In the following I will hard-code the input for simplicity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string months[] = {
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April" , "May" , "June",
        "July" , "August" , "September",
        "October", "November", "December"
    };

    double rainfall[] = {
        1.1, 2.2, 3.3,
        0.9, 6.7, 8.4,
        0.3, 7.8, 10.2,
        0.4, 12.1, 5.7
    };

    double min_rain = 0.0, max_rain = 0.0;
    std::string min_month, max_month;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || rainfall[i] < min_rain) {
            min_rain = rainfall[i];
            min_month = months[i];
        }

        if (rainfall[i] > max_rain) {
           max_rain = rainfall[i];
           max_month = months[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << min_month << " had the least rain." << std::endl
              << max_month << " had the most rain."  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This isn't actually all that bad. But now let's imagine we want to *sort* them. Now it gets more complicated maintaining the corresponding order.

But instead, what if we store our data using an aggregate data structure? Now we have just one array which we can readily sort with [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) by providing a custom comparator in the form of a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct RainData {
    std::string month;
    double rainfall;
};

int main() {
    RainData data[] = {
        {"January", 1.1}, {"February", 2.2}, {"March", 3.3},
        {"April", 0.9}, {"May", 6.7}, {"June", 8.4},
        {"July", 0.3}, {"August", 7.8}, {"September", 10.2},
        {"October", 0.4}, {"November", 12.1}, {"December", 5.7}
    };

    std::sort(
      data, data+12,
      [](auto a, auto b){
        return a.rainfall > b.rainfall;
      }
    );

    std::cout << data[0].month << " had the least." << std::endl
              << data[11].month << " had the most." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```